# Set image resource in onCreate method

Tags: android, image

Is it possible to set image resource in onCreate method before loading layout.

For example:

On main layout I have images instead of buttons, so there is no button "Play", instead there is an image on which "Play" is drawn. 
But, on other hand, user can change languages, so if user choses German there has to be different image on main layout.
I know how to change picture on some event, but is it possible to do it in onCreate method.

Logic would probably be something like:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences options= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        String language= options.getString("language", "en");
        setLocal(language);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView play= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);

        if(language=="en")
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_en);
        else if(language=="de")
            play.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_de);


    }
```

Of course, this doesn't change the picture because image is already loaded, but I hope you get what I want to achieve.

Comment: You could easily test this by setting the `res` to one `drawable` in xml then trying to set it in `onCreate()` to another `drawable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wan't to do can be done using localization on your resources, I think this is te correct and easily way to do it.
You can check how, here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html